# Знаки вопроса вместо букв в echo

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь вывести букву из слова.

```
$slovo="Привет";
echo $slovo[2];
```

Вместо буквы выводится знак вопроса в ромбе.
Кодировка стоит utf-8 без BOM.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш вариант с кириллицей не работает.

Вот рабочий вариант.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo substr('Слово', 0, 2); // результат "С"
```

**P.S** Функция `substr()` 1 букву кириллицы воспринимает как 2 символа, поэтому в примере стоит `0, 2`, то есть начиная с нулевого символа, печатать 2 символа(т.е. 1 букву).

Comment: Спасибо, но нет!
И на будущее, используйте mb_substr .
В этом случае можно писать так echo mb_substr($slovo, 0, 1);

Comment: @LEgXr если вы мне советуете что использовать, то зачем вы написали неработающий код?

Answer (score 0):

В .htaccess пропиши:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: .htaccess нет, а его создание и добавление данной строки не помогло